# Cypress: Element not found inside cypress

Tags: angularjs, iframe, automated-tests, mocha.js, cypress

Content is inside the iframe:

```
 it.only('should verify xyz tooltips',()=>{
    cy.visit('/');
    cy.get('a[ng-reflect-router-link="abc"]').click();
   
    cy.wait(9000)
    cy.get('iframe')
    .then( ($iframe) => {
        const $body = $iframe.contents().find('body')
        cy.wrap($body).find('.content').invoke('attr','style', 'overflow: visible')

        //upto here it is working fine

        cy.wrap($body).find('div.visTooltip').invoke('attr','style', 'visibility: 
         visible').invoke('attr','style', 'overflow: visible')
        
        //Below statement is not working
         cy.wrap($body).find('div.visTooltip > table.visTooltip__table').should('have.length',1)
                  
    })
});
```

**HTML of the page that is not working**

[image]

I'm successfully able to locate upto div tag using  `cy.wrap($body).find('div.visTooltip')` but after that code is not finding table inside div tag.
I tried setting up css property *visibility and overflow to visible* but nothing is working.
Can somebody please have a look and suggest something?

Comment: Have you tried `cy.wait()` for wait load html ?

Comment: yeah, i tried that as well. No Luck!@Jboucly

Comment: I keep running into similar problems with Cypress. It just cannot find elements that are clearly present. It keeps happening if unpredictable ways  I'm strongly leaning towards the opinion that Cypress is just too unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cypress example on how to use find?
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/find.html#Syntax

Example from link above

Get li’s within parent

```
<ul id="parent">
  <li class="first"></li>
  <li class="second"></li>
</ul>
```

```
// yields [<li class="first"></li>, <li class="second"></li>]
cy.get('#parent').find('li')
```